# Forge AR/VR Toolkit manifest always returns status failed

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-arvr

I've been trying to use the *Autodesk Forge AR/VR Toolkit* from http://forgetoolkit.com/#/unityPackage to get the Revit 2020 sample project `rst_basic_sample_project.rvt` from https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/setup which I already translated to SVF format working in Unity. The model is available under the model URN in *Forge Viewer* as shown in the image attached.

Following the documentation at https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/create_scene I ran the arkit requests in sequence.
All responses look fine and the corresponding data is created as the following response to the GET request https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/arkit/v1/:urn/scenes/:sceneid shows:

```
{
    "prj": {
        "bucket": "unity-test-02",
        "object": "rst_basic_sample_project.rvt",
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dW5pdHktdGVzdC0wMi9yc3RfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0",
        "view_id": "2b8b1cf8-31bf-7e71-dfb5-e1d4342ddb82"
    }
}
```

After triggering the POST request https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/arkit/v1/:urn/scenes/:sceneid with response:

```
{
    "result": "created",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dW5pdHktdGVzdC0wMi9yc3RfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0",
    "acceptedJobs": {
        "output": {
            "formats": [
                {
                    "type": "arkit",
                    "scene": "unity-04"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I run the GET request https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/:urn/manifest to check the job's status. It always returns `"status": "failed"` for any of the arkit scenes I created so far.
Here is the `"outputType": "arkit"` part of the response:

```
...
        {
            "status": "failed",
            "outputType": "arkit",
            "children": [
                {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "reason": "unknown",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "unity-01"
                },
                {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "reason": "unknown",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "unity-02"
                },
                {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "reason": "unknown",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "unity-03"
                },
                {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "reason": "unknown",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "unity-04"
                }
            ],
            "progress": "complete"
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "success"
}
```

I tried it with Revit 2022 and Navisworks 2020 files as well as using SVF2 format instead of SVF always with the same result. The hint `"reason": "unknown"` is not very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer for the AR/VR Toolkit issue unfortunately but I would like to suggest a different approach of bringing Forge models into Unity, one that I've been proposing to Forge customers for a while now, and that's been getting good feedback:

There's a Node.js library - https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils - that you can use to convert SVF files from Forge into the open 3D exchange format called [glTF](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/). With your designs in the glTF format you can then leverage the rich ecosystem of utilities such as Unity or Unreal Engine loaders, geometry optimizers, etc. Recently I've put together a sample app that showcases this approach: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-unity-poc.